# How to you invoke a particular email client in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to invoke a specific email client(lotus note traveler email client) directly without opening the email client picker dialog box, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check and see if there is an intent available for that specific application, and call that intent, along with your normal "putExtra" (for subject line, body, etc.). Otherwise you'll have to call the default email intent (android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND) and then set the default to the mail client you want to work with.